# c# Random Class in a While Loop

Tags: c#

```
 while (true)
 {         
     Console.Write("What is: " + num03 + " x " + num04 + " = ");
     int answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
     if (answer == num03 * num04)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Correct");
         num03 = randNum.Next(10) + 1;
         num04 = randNum.Next(10) + 1;
         continue;
     }
     else
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Incorrect");
         continue;
     }
 }// End of while loop
```

I'm new to C# (2 weeks in) Randomize for simple math sums. 
Is there an easier or more compact way to write `randNum.Next()` for each variable?

Comment: Not really. Do you find it too long?? You can always pull out code into a function (with a really short name like `r`), but it certainly doesn't make any sense here.

Comment: No, I guess I just wanted check it as I'm teaching myself. I suppose I'll get more confident as I write. Thanks TaW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no shorter way than that, unless you use some lambda or other method to do so something like this:

```
var rnd = new Random(); // add a seed if required
Func<int> randNum = () => rnd.Next(1, 11); // I think your intent was to get a number between 1 and 11 right? You can always change that

while(true)
{
     Console.Write("What is: " + num03 + " x " + num04 + " = ");
     int answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
     if (answer == num03 * num04)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Correct");
         num03 = randNum();
         num04 = randNum();
     }
     else
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Incorrect");
     }
}
```

notice I removed the `continue` since they were not needed as you cover both cases of the if, so whatever block gets executed (*then* or *else*) will lead to the end of the loop which just makes it go another *lap*.

another options is have:

```
Action randNum = 
    () => {
              num03 = rand.Next(1, 11);
              num04 = rand.Next(1, 11);
          };
```

and in your loop:

```
while(true)
{
     Console.Write("What is: " + num03 + " x " + num04 + " = ");
     int answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
     if (answer == num03 * num04)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Correct");
         randNum();
     }
     else
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Incorrect");
     }
}
```

though I think all this to be an overkill for such small this you could very well do it, in any case the one I'd recommend if you were to **actually** do one of these is the *first* one

Comment: Overkill is exactly what I need. I'm going to build on this small/simple code over the next few days so this helps a lot. Thanks

Comment: @PCFriendly if an answer fixes your problem, it's good to go ahead and upvote / accept the answer, by clicking the green arrow next to it.